# Z3py how to solve a problem with many possible path (k out of n potential actions, order matters) efficiently

Tags: z3, z3py

I am trying to solve a problem that consists of n actions (n >= 8). A path consists k (k == 4 for now) actions. I would like to check if there exists any path, which satisfies the set of constraints I defined.

I have made two attempts to solve this problem:

**Attempt 1**: Brute force, try all permutations

**Attempt 2**: Code a path selection matrix `M [k x n]`, such that each row contains one and only one element greater than 0, and all other elements equal to 0.

For instance if `k == 2`, `n == 2`, `M = [[0.9, 0], [0, 0.7]]` represents perform action 1 first, then action 2.

Then my state transition was coded as:

```
S1 = a2(a1(S0, M[1][1]), M[1][2]) = a2(a1(S0, 0.9), 0)

S2 = a2(a1(S1, M[2][1]), M[2][2]) = a2(a1(S1, 0), 0.7)
```

Note: I made sure that `S == a(S,0)`, so that in each step only one action is executed.

Then constraints were checked on S2

I was hoping this to be faster than the permutation way of doing it. Unfortunately, this turns out to be slower. Just wondering if there is any better way to solve this problem?

Code:

```
_path = [[Real(f'step_{_i}_action_{_j}') for _j in range(len(actions))] for _i in range(number_of_steps)]
_states: List[State] = [self.s0]
for _i in range(number_of_steps):
    _new_state = copy.deepcopy(_states[-1])
    for _a, _p in zip(actions, _path[_i]):
        self.solver.add(_a.constraints(_states[-1], _p))
        _new_state = _a.execute(_new_state, _p)
        _states.append(_new_state)
```

Comment: Impossible to answer this without actually knowing what your constraints actually are. Can you extract a minimum example that we can run? It should be self-contained.

Comment: Do I misunderstand, or do you explicitly fix and try each possible permutation? Why not let it be a free variable and allow the SMT solver to generate it?